# Why is my browser freezing while doing a counting for child elements inside a container div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am using this jquery GanttView library to generate a Gantt Chart - https://github.com/thegrubbsian/jquery.ganttView

After the Gantt has been generated, I am executing following jQuery code to count child elements inside the ganttchart generated html:

```
$('.ganttview-grid').children().length
```

But it is freezing the browser to about 40 seconds and there aren't really much child elements inside the container (about 460 child elements exist inside this div recognized by `$('.ganttview-grid')`.

Can someone tell me, how much data is too much for jQuery handling or reading, or is there a faster way to compute this without browser freeze?

Comment: You can add 1 to a variable everytime an child element is generated.

Comment: Write the code better to not freeze the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried with the sample page:

http://thegrubbsian.github.io/jquery.ganttView/example/index.html

and the script that you posted doesn't showed any problem (these are only 17 childs). Generally I've used jQuery to retrieve list of thousand or ten thousands elements without any problem. Are you really sure that it's this line to freeze your browser ? try placing a return in the line below to be sure that the problem is not some place after this call.

Generally working with the DOM is slow but not so slow that you can feel an operation like retrieving 500 elements. A simple way to speedup it is to store those elements when you draw it or to infer them from your starting data. They are number of elements that you passed to jQuery Gantt to draw and count those javascript elements is way faster than parsing the generated DOM. Try posting your code and we can help you about this.

Last test, I've never done a benchmark maybe this is faster:

```
$('.ganttview-block').length
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes counting in a variable may do the trick, didn't thought of that silly me :-) ... I'll try that out.

Comment: Eheh the simplest solutions are always the ones that you don't think to when you have a problem. Please choose ma answer if works ;-)

Comment: I've marked the awnser here, as it was helpful to me. But just so everyone who come across later, I would like to confirm that this actually did not help my situation. My freeze was still there, it turned out to be freezing on another line of code I used that was determining top potion of the element inside the Gantt container. The ultimate solution turned out to be to do paged display of Gantt here, and not all items to be shown in 1 go. adding elements to DOM was not taking the toll on freeze but making changes or accessing DOM element by javascript is actually causing the freeze.